# How to localize a Netbeans MenuBar created from the layer file?

Tags: java, netbeans, internationalization, netbeans-platform

I use the `org.openide.awt.MenuBar(DataFolder)` constructor to automatically build a MenuBar from actions registered in the layer.xml file:

```
menuBar = new MenuBar(DataFolder.findFolder(FileUtil.getConfigFile("MyMenuBar")));
```

And below is an example of the `ImportMix` action registration in the "MixFile" submenu:

```
@ActionID(category = "MixConsole", id = "org.jjazz.ui.mixconsole.actions.importmix")
@ActionRegistration(displayName = "#CTL_ImportMix", lazy = true)
@ActionReferences(
        {
            @ActionReference(path = "MyMenuBar/MixFile", position = 200)
        })
public class ImportMix extends AbstractAction
```

I can easily localize the `ImportMix` action name, but how to localize the submenu name ?  ("MixFile" in the example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally got it.

There is the `displayName` attribute that can be added to a `layer.xml` folder, and the attribute value can be redirected to a localizable Bundle property.

The easier way to do it is to edit `layer.xml` via Netbeans IDE:

- select the folder "MixFile" (in my example)
- right-click "Localize Name"
- enter the name of the default display name

It automatically adds the attribute and updates the `Bundle.properties` with a new property ready to be localized.